# Retrieve original destination information from IBM MQ message

Tags: ibm-mq

I am very new to IBM MQ and I am trying to write an application to consume messages from a common queue that might have originally been sent to an alias queue or topic before being routed to the common queue.  After GETting the message I want to be able to perform conditional logic based on the specific destination of the message.

In RabbitMq we have the ability to get the original RoutingKey used to publish the message. This allows me to subscribe using a wild card, but then do something special for each message based on the actual RoutingKey.

I am currently using a plain installation of IBM MQ.  Is it possible to determine the original destination (Alias Queue or topic) of the message before MQ re-routed it?

Can MQ manipulate the message (property, MQMD field, etc...) during routing so that I could pull the custom value out once it is retrieved?

If I cannot do this with the plain version of MQ is there an additional tool that I can add-on to MQ that would accommodate this functionality (I've seen many posts about IBM Integration Bus, formerly Message Broker, but I still can't wrap my head around exactly what it does or if it will meet my needs.)

I am programming in .Net and I have played with both XMS and the plain .Net client tools available through amqmdnet.dll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the messages have been published to a topic and from there routed to a queue based on a subscription the messages will contain the MQTopicString message property which gives you the topic string that they were published to.

As an example, use the browse sample amqsbcg to view the messages on the queue with the third argument set to '1' (amqsbcg   1). If you have message properties in the message they will be listed as...

****Message properties****

MQTopicString : '/A/B/C'

Comment: This got me going in the right direction!  I found that the property name was "mqps.Top" rather than "MQTopicString", but it did hold the original topic string used to publish the message.  I also verified that this property is set when using an Alias Queue to forward to a topic.

Answer (score 1):

MQ is middleware used by many applications, if they started to integrate support for every application logic, it would get really messy, that's why MQ manages only so much information that is required to get the messages from sender to receiver.
In general I don't think it's a good practice to use the mechanisms of the transport layer to support application logic. By doing so, you introduce too deep dependencies on your transport solution.

Any information used by the communicating applications to provide their services should be included in the message by the sender and receiver applications.
MQ provides the means to transfer information, not to create or manage it.

For example you could write your sender application so that it includes the sender applications id in the message properties. MQ will transfer these properties and provide means to get messages by these properties.

To your further questions, by default MQ cannot manipulate the messages transferred (aside from code page conversion), that's what Message Broker (IIB) is for.
But Message Broker doesn't integrate into MQ, it only uses MQ as a transport mechanism, so it will not help with determining originator of messages when the messages are routed fully by MQ.
If the messages are routed by the Message Broker, then it can include any information in the messages sent.

Answer (score 0):

No, the object name that was used by the producer is lost. Although some `MQMD` headers such as `PutApplName`, `ReplyToQ` or `ReplyToQMgr` may be helpful in deducing the origin of the message.

It is my opinion that having many-to-one queue endpoints is a bad practice for WMQ implementations.

Comment: I have thought of using those fields, however the list of possible values could be quite long.  Just curious why many-to-one would be bad practice?  To me it seems like having every publisher sending to their own queue and then trying to read from all of those separate queues is a management nightmare.  Every time I add another publisher I'd have to add an additional process to consume that queue.

Comment: This is all fine until you try to figure out who sent what. If there was a foolproof way of achieving what you ask I'd have no problem with multiple producing endpoints.